# Using new hotmail.com 'send as feature' results in a 'from <live email> on behalf of <sent as email>', anyway to 'fix' that?

Tags: email, outlook, gmail

With outlook.com I can opt to send emails from other accounts, but when I do send an email the 'from' is formatted as: 'Sent by myemail@live.com on behalf of theEmailIWantToSendAs@gmail.com'.

Would it be possible to just have 'theEmailIWantToSendAs@gmail.com' instead and completely hide myemail@live.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this Outlook annoyance (displaying the headers in the wrong sequence) cannot be fixed on the side of webmail providers. At least not on the public ones which do not allow scripting. Sometimes - depending on your use case - using `Reply-To` is better.